# Lower bound on diameter of a set that still contains "most" of the measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\nu$ be a probability measure that is supported on a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ of finite diameter , i.e $diam(S)=d<\infty$ and $\nu(S)=1$. Given $c\in [0,1]$, I was interested (for a generic measure $\nu$) to find the smallest diameter $s$ such that there is a set $A$ with $diam(A)=s$ and $\nu(A)\ge c$. Maybe we cannot find the exact diameter but what is for a generic measure the best lower bound (depending on $c$ and the dimension of the space $d$) for this diameter,i.e. $\exists A$ with $diam(A)\le$ [lower bound] such that $\nu(A)\ge c$.